# Delphi Pas2Dox + Doxygen

Tags: delphi, comments, doxygen

I am using Delphi and I need to prepare some documentation. One of possible solutions to that is to use Doxygen with Pas2Dox filter.

I am currently using pas2dox-0.50rc1.exe filter and Doxygen wizard 1.8.3.1. I am struggling to setup Doxygen properly to display my comments in Delphi but the thing is that I am not sure anymore what is the proper comment format in Delphi. I searched interenet but I can't find any tutorial or example on how to succesfully generate html documentation with delphi.

Is there maybe somebody who can share me some tips how to achieve that?

My current comments are as:

```
{*------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  test
  @param AGraphicsOwner   ParameterDescription
  @param ASettingsPath   ParameterDescription
  @param AEngineType   ParameterDescription
  @return ResultDescription
------------------------------------------------------------------------------*}
constructor TBaseEngine.Create(AGraphicsOwner: HWND;
                               ASettingsPath: PAnsiChar;
                               AEngineType: byte);
```

THANKS!!

Comment: Using `{*  *}` should be fine for your comments.

Comment: `(** ... *)` works well with pasdox 0.41

Answer (score 1):

I succeeded in creating a nice doxygen documentation with comments formated exactly like yours on my delphi code!

Here is how:

1. Replace all not-doxygen comments with // : 
   instead of

   ```
   (* comment *) or { comment }
   ```

   have

   ```
   // comment
   ```

   **Why?** According to [this blog entry](http://docmartinscodingstuff.blogspot.de/2012/10/pas2dox-doxygen-comments-tips-and-tricks.html) for the pas2dox filter it is crucial not to use (* and *) for commentaries in your delphi file. Furthermore simple one-line commentaries embraced by { and } seem to destroy the doxygen documentation as well.
2. Put the methods you want to see documented in doxygen into the INTERFACE section: 
   Only the methods "declared" in the INTERFACE section will be visible in doxygen (I have not quite figured out why, yet)

I tested it with a file that had all types of delphi comment-styles. I replaced the comment-idicators with notepad++'s replace-all function in the following order (I am completely sure there is a more elegant way to do that, but for me it was handy):

- replace { with //
- replace //$ with {$
- replace (* with //

after that, all methods (in the INTERFACE section) appeared in doxygen and I started to comment using the doxygen style from above. I left away the ---, but I don't think this should be an issue =)